# Install Ubuntu and upgrade Windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ssd

I'm running Windows 7 on my laptop.
I'm going to upgrade to Windows 8 and also installing Ubuntu along side.

My questions:

1. Should I install Ubuntu to my SSD ? ( I have windows 7 on HDD and can't create more partition)
2. I'm planning to upgrade to Windows 8 AFTER install Ubuntu, is that okay? (I have UEFI disabled, currently on Legacy boot so I guess the order does not matter?)
3. I have Intel Smart Storage Tech. (SSD cache) should I disable it when upgrade/install Ubuntu and Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you'll be able to install Ubuntu onto a solid state drive, given that it is large and fast enough, though performance has always been greater on HDD for me, why are you unable to create more partitions?

I always install Linux second so that I can use GRUB to boot to both Linux, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (I installed the three alongside).

I can't imagine you having problems with Intel SST though, if you do, feel free to return to the Askubuntu community with a new question!

Make sure to mark any answers you deem acceptable as answered to keep the community going.

Comment: Do you have any idea to dualboot Ubuntu and Win8 with UEFI?
It looks like Ubuntu can't recognize wind8

Comment: There is a documentation for installing Ubuntu next to Windows on a EUFI dual boot located [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) if you need a more experienced hand?

Answer (score 0):

I am using SSD i have installed windows 8 first then i have installed Ubuntu beside it

[image]

Comment: My SSD is only have ~10GB left, do you think that's enough ?

Comment: Yeah i think it will be enough